# How to call function defined in jsp from servlet?

Tags: javascript, jsp, servlets

For example I have javascript function in my index.jsp:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function myFunction(){
        alert("HI FROM Index.jsp");
    }
</script>
```

How can I call it from servlet?

Comment: P.S I mean calling by it name.

Comment: You can't do that. What's your actual requirement? Why are you need javascript function in servlet?

Comment: @VinothKrishnan When user put wrong information to login fields i want to      highlight this fields and, maybe add some text.

Comment: Please help us with paste your code what you done so far. Otherwise you haven't start please go through some tutorials and comeback if you stuck with somewhere.

Comment: @VinothKrishnan Thank you for your answer. What tutuorial do you recomend?

Comment: Go through [this](http://javaknowledge.info/jstl-1-1-simple-login-and-logout-example-with-session/) and [this](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0vUI_PKcHSI)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use ajax for your requirement. Use $.post to submit your parameters to servlet and process the data obtained from the servlet i.e. success or failure and hence call your javascript function accordingly. For details on $.post refer to the following link.

http://api.jquery.com/jquery.post/

Comment: Thank you. This link also very useful
http://www.simplecodestuffs.com/ajax-implementation-in-jsp-servlet-using-jquery-and-json/